# Yii2: Trying to get property of non-object with customized SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2

I want to give colors to rows of a GridView. But Yii2 show an error. It is like the model doesn't exist:

[image: Showing the error "Trying to get property of non-object"]
This is part of my **index** view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    function($model) {
        if ($model->quantity == 0) {
            return ['class' => 'danger'];
        }
    },
    'columns' => [
        'item',
        'quantity',
    ],
]) ?>
```

The data to fill the GridView is coming from a SQL query in the **ProductsSearch** model:

```
$query = Products::find()
    ->select(['item', 'quantity']);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 
    'query' => $query->asArray(),
    'key' => 'item',
]);

return $dataProvider;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
if ($model->quantity == 0) {
    return ['class' => 'danger'];
}
```

I changed it to:

```
if ($model['quantity'] == 0) {
    return ['class' => 'danger'];
}
```